# urlretrieve returning typeerror

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I don't know why my code is returning this error, I can't seem to debug it.

`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Here is what I'm using to download

```
self.headers = { 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' }
self.request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=self.headers)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.request, reporthook=report)
```

Comment: I don't think `urlretrieve` allows the sending of headers. Does it work without them?

Comment: No, it returns a `403 Forbidden` to my webserver. Does that mean I'll have to alter my website?

Comment: Let me ask you this: can you get by without using the `reporthook`? Because then you can use `urlopen` which allows headers.

Comment: I need `reporthook` with `PyQt5` to send the progress of the download to a progressbar, so I kinda need it.

Comment: Oh I see. I think `urlretrieve` should allow the sending of headers. Not sure why it doesn't...

Comment: It's a strange error. I've never gotten this before.

Comment: Well it's because `urlretrieve` doesn't expect a `Request` object there. It expects a URL.

Comment: Oh it's to your own webserver! Yeah can't you whitelist it or something like that?

Comment: I'll look at my `nginx` configuration. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers for the help. :-)

Comment: Cool. Anytime! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `urlretrieve` doesn't allow the sending of headers.

And the error you're getting is because `urlretrieve` is expecting a URL there and not a `Request` object.

Since it's your own webserver you're sending the request to maybe you can modify its configuration to accept those `urlretrieve` requests without headers.

Best of luck.