# urllib.urlretrieve with custom header

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlretrieve

I am trying to retrieve a file using `urlretrieve`, while adding a custom header.

While checking the codesource of `urllib.request` I realized `urlopen` can take a `Request` object in parameter instead of just a string, allowing to put the header I want.
But if I try to do the same with `urlretrieve`, I get a [TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022570/urlretrieve-returning-typeerror) as mentionned in this other post.

What I ended up doing is rewriting my own urlretrieve, removing the line throwing the error (that line is irrelevant in my use case).

**It works fine** but I am wondering if there is a **better/cleaner** way of doing it, rather than rewriting my own `urlretrieve`. If it is possible to pass a custom header to `urlopen`, it feels like it should be possible to do the same with `urlretrieve`?

Comment: Try to use urllib2. i got also same error one time.but after changing urllib2 it will works

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I found a way where you only have to add a few extra lines of code...

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
urllib.request.urlretrieve("type URL here", "path/file_name")
```

Should you wish to learn about the details you can refer to the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Answer (score 8):

The `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` use inside `urllib.request.urlopen()` (at least in Python 3). So you can use same way how you can influence behavior of `urlopen`.

When `urlopen(params)` is invoked it actually first looks at the special global variable `urllib.request._opener` and if it is `None` then the `urlopen` set the variable with default set of openers otherwise it will keep it as it. In the next step it will call `urllib.request._opener.open(<urlopen_params>)` (in next sections I will refer `urllib.request._opener` only as `opener`).

The `opener.open()` contains list of handlers for different protocols. When the `opener.open()` is called then it will do this actions:

1. Creates from URL `urllib.request.Request` object (or if you provide directly the `Request` it will just use it).
2. From the `Request` object is extracted the protocol (it deduced from URL scheme).
3. Based on the protocol it will try lookup and use those methods:

   - `protocol_request` (e.g. `http_request`) - it used for pre-process the request before the connection is opened.
   - `protocol_open` - actually creates connection with the remote server
   - `protocol_response` - process the response from the server
   - for other methods look at the [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.OpenerDirector.add_handler)

For your own opener you have to do those 3 steps:

1. Create own handler
2. Build list of handlers contains your custom handler (function `urllib.request.build_opener`)
3. Install the new opener into `urllib.request._opener` (function `urllib.request.install_opener`)

The `urllib.request.build_opener` creates opener which contains your custom handler and add default openers except handlers from which is your custom handler inherited.

So for adding custom header you can write something like this:

```
import urllib.request as req

class MyHTTP(req.HTTPHandler):
    def http_request(self, req):
        req.headers["MyHeader"] = "Content of my header"
        return super().http_request(req)

opener = req.build_opener(MyHTTP())
req.install_opener(opener)
```

From this point when you call `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` or anything which is using the `urlopen()` it will use for HTTP communication your handler. When you want to get back to default handlers you can just call:

```
import urllib.request as req   

req.install_opener(req.build_opener())
```

To be honest I don't know if it is better/cleaner solution then yours but it uses prepared mechanisms in the `urllib`.

Comment: I feel this is really overkill but I award you the bounty anyway as it was really interesting answer concerning urllib. Anyway I switched to using the `requests` lib instead